# CSS descendent selector does not update element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the border of a target descendant element with no luck. Using the descendant selector for the following HTML does not work. If anyone has any suggestions on what I may be doing incorrectly I would greatly appreciate any input

```css
.parent .target {
     border: solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> 
     <div class="grandchild">
         <div class="target"></div>
         <div class="great-grandchild"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's with the odd second quote in `<div class="child”> `

Comment: does my answer solve your code issue? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.parent .target {
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

you need to set border height.
also your code has syntax issue you have to use **"**  between class names not **“**.

```css
.parent .target {
     border: 1px solid red;
   
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
         <div class="child"> 
           <div class="grandchild">
              <div class="target"></div>
              <div class="great-grandchild"></div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your CSS descendent selector and it appears to be working fine.

Your HTML snippet appears to be mixing quote styles which prevents anything from showing up so I would go through your HTML and make sure you've used the same quotes throughout.